# Quill JS | Implement multi page functionality

Tags: quill, react-quill, ngx-quill

I am trying to implement multipage functionality with quill. I want to fix the height of each page, and when user reaches the end of page, instead of editor height to grow or scrollbar to appear, I want cursor to go to next page(editor), similar behaviour as observed in Google Docs or Microsoft word document.
I have already added 2 editors in the view, but not having any idea on how to switch to new page as cursor reaches the end of first page.

Answer (score 0):

i come straight from google trying to figure out something similar with quill and as far as i know and as far as i came while researching this specific topic:

to me it seems as if its not possible with multiple editors since as soon as the user wants to select paragraphs/elements over a multi page span you'd have to figure out how to

- make the selection actually possible (try to select content over a span of two div elements which both are "contenteditable"-enabled, which was one of my first tries kinda).
- spread the selection on multiple editors (you'd have to keep track of how much the user selected and when and how far the selection is within which editor which is kinda tricky)
- execute an action over multiple editors which will be especially hard since there is no thing as "shared toolbar" yet (as far as i know)

so i really hope () the time helped you to find an sharable  solution to this but as far as i built up my knowledge about quill so far (which is a bit over a few weeks old now).

what i will try in the near future is to add a new module to show a page break and style all other elements accordingly to simulate the look of a page.